# Difference between “Where did she go?” and “Where is she?"

Tags: meaning, difference, past-tense, present-tense

Please, explain the difference of meaning between these questions.

1. Where did she go?
2. Where is she?

How can I explain the difference between them to my student?

Comment: The title is almost meaningless and far too vague for future visitors. Please see this guide which explains *why* a good title is useful for you, the asker, and for users who enjoy answering questions. http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2630/how-can-i-write-a-better-title-for-my-ell-question/2631#2631 I would strongly suggest that you change the question title to something more specific. P.S. You also forgot to write *she* with a small letter.

Comment: what title would be more appropriate please?

Comment: Well... the one that I had suggested in my edit before you reverted it back. You also changed the personal pronoun in Q2. it's now a "he", before it was a "she"! Not that it makes a huge difference but... still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explain your student the difference in meaning, compare the following

1. Where was she?
2. **Where is she?**

Question no.1 refers to a particular time in the  past, the speaker does not know where the person *was*. In theory, "was" could refer to any time in the past, but context will tell us  if the speaker is talking about ten minutes or ten years ago.

Question no.2 refers to the **present**, i.e., "now". The speaker does not know the whereabouts of a person at the time of speaking. "She" **is** not *here*.

Compare
3. Where does she go?
4. **Where did she go?**

Question 3 is most likely referring to somebody's daily routine e.g.,
*Where does she go [on Saturday(s)]?*

Question 4 refers to an episode in the specific **past** that the speaker has in mind e.g.,
*Where di she go [on Saturday]?*

However, questions 2 and 4 can be used in an everyday situation as shown below

Alice: Is Fiona around?
Bob: No, she's not
Alice: **Where is she?**
Bob: Out. I saw her leaving.
Alice: **Where did she go?**
Bob: She didn't say.

Answer (score 1):

Both questions are used when she is not nearby and you're wondering where she is, however there are differences

> **A**) Where did she go?

You know she went to a particular destination and you want to know what the destination was

> **B**) Where is she?

She is at some location, maybe moving to some other place or maybe stationary, and you want to know where she is

If you know **A** you might ask about **B**
You may know where she is going (**A**), but not where she is right now (**B**).

If you know **B** you might ask about **A**
You may know where she is right now (**A**) but not where she is going (**A**).

If you know **A** and **B**, you can know how far she has travelled towards her destination.
If you don't know either **A** or **B**, you're out of luck...

Answer (score 1):

I think

> where is she?

means its state.

> where did she go?

means its action basically.
(The tense doesn't matter here)

Answer (score 0):

> Where is she?

Is time specific to ***now***.

> Where did she go?

Is not time specific, except that it is in the past. It could be today, yesterday, or last year.